# Is $2^{\infty}$ an Indeterminate form

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

We know that when $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \to 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x) \to \infty$$ then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$$ is an indeterminate form since in the neighbourhood of $a$ we cannot predict the exact value to where the limit approaches.

Is it indeterminate if the limit is in $2^{\infty}$ form?

Comment: $2$  raised to a large power is very large.

Comment: ya i also thought same but had a doubt. if we talk about $1^{\infty}$ if function approaches $1$ from left that is $0.99999^{\infty}$ is very small but if $f(x)$ approaches $1$ from right that is $1.00001^{\infty}$ is very large. Hence $1^{\infty}$ is indeterminate. Similarly if in case of $2$, $1.999^{\infty}$  is large and also $2.00001^{\infty}$  is also large. so from both sides $2^{\infty}$ is large, hence it is not Indeterminate. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: The behaviour of $f(x)^{g(x)}$, where $f(x)$ has limit #1#, and $g(x)$ blows up, can be very complex. Using the non-number $\infty$ as an exponent is not a good idea, it will lead to wrong answers. Your description of the case limit of $f(x)$ is $2$ is intuitively reasonable, but again it is a good idea not to use $\infty$ as an exponent.

Answer (score 2):

**No** , $2^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form.

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ then to get $f(x)^{g(x)}>M$, just make sure $x$ is close enough to $a$ so that $f(x)>1.1$ for any closer value (possible since $f(x)$ can be kept close to $2$) and so that $g(x)$ is greater than $\log_{1.1}M$ (possible since $g(x)$ can be made arbitrarily large).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $2^x$ as $e^{x\ln 2}$. You have

- $e^u \xrightarrow[u\to \infty]{} \infty$;
- The function $\exp$ is continuous; and
- $x\ln 2 \xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} \infty$ (as $\ln 2 > 0$).

Combining the 3, $e^{x\ln 2} \xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} \infty$.

Not that this does *not* work for your case $f(x) \xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} 1$, as then $\ln f(x) \xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} 0$ and you do not have the argument  "$x\ln f(x) \xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} \infty$." (There is an indeterminate form there.)

Comment: I don't understand why passing from the continuous function $2^x$ to the continuous function $e^x$ serves as an explanation.

Comment: Because the fact that $\exp$ is continuous is more "basic" than the fact that $x\mapsto a^x$ is continous for constant $a> 1$ (the latter is generally defined based on the former), and because this allows to treat the case $f(x)^x$ in the same manner. (I.e., when the base is *not* a constant, reverting to $\exp$ is safe and works.)

Comment: For your first point, I have some calculus books that start from $e^x$ and some that start from $2^x$, but it may very well be more common to start from $e^x$. For your second point, reverting to $2^x$ is equally "safe" if you replace the natural log with the base-2 log. The reason $e$ and $\ln$ are common in these situations is for the purposes of applying L'Hospital's rule, which is not necessary to argue about whether $f(x)^{g(x)}$ leads to an indeterminate form.

Comment: ?! This has absolutely nothing to do with L'Hospital rule. Yes, one could use $x\mapsto 2^x$ as "base case," but I'd argue this is by far much less common -- at least, I have never seen it used as the basis for exponentiation in the reals (let alone the complex) in any textbook or class. (As a hint, I'd also say $\exp$ is a standard name for the function for a reason.) But if that makes you feel better, replace the $e$ by $2$ and $\ln$ by $\log_2$ in the above: this will not change anything to the last paragraph.

Comment: I agree that the original question and questions about whether or not $f(x)^{g(x)}$ would be related to an indeterminate form. I'm just saying that I think the only reason not to be base-agnostic about arguments of the form in your answer would be if you wanted to prepare someone for L'Hospital's rule. If L'Hospital's rule is not in the picture (as I think we agree), then base $2$ or $3$ is just as safe as base $e$.

Comment: But, no, again L'Hospital rule is not the reason for the use of this. $\exp$ as it is has much more reasons to be introduced than this, you are confusing a thing and one of its (multiple) uses. Power series, definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ as such, relations with $\ln$, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35573/discussion-between-mark-s-and-clement-c).